# SEVERE: A child container failed during start: But same project runs fine on different PC

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, server

I have switched my PC and my maven project is not running fine. Now it is showing ***Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.***

[image: This Shows every time i run the project]

I've done several things:

1. Removed project from eclipse
2. Deleted the server(Apache tomcat 8)
3. Again imported the project and set Targeted Runtimes
4. Changed workspace

In the console of eclipse it shows as:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
Failed to start component
[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SystemDevelopment]]
```

Comment: Can you please provide more logs, and/or source code?

Comment: Can you also provide details of your maven or gradle build file

Comment: Oct 22, 2018 5:33:47 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SystemDevelopment]]
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.wst.server.core 4 0 2018-10-22 17:33:48.303
!MESSAGE Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start.